# NeutralinoJS: error: missing required argument 'name'

Tags: neutralinojs

I tried to create my first NeutralinoJS app using neu-cli. I typed `neu create --template hello-world` command in Windows Command Prompt as in the [doucmentation](https://neutralino.js.org/docs/#/gettingstarted/firstapp). But it gives me this error.

> error: missing required argument 'name'

So I typed it again in git bash. But it gives the same error again. How to fix this ? Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Command syntax is like this :

```
neu create <App_Name> --template <Template_Type>
```

Supported template types are :

- js
- ts
- kotlin
- react

Example :- `neu create MyApp --template js`